# Convert JSON date to a JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, java, json, date, gson

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(date));
```

The output is: `Mar 11, 2016 3:13:04 PM`.

This date is being sent to the UI layer where I am not able to convert it to the javascript date object.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: use the momentjs library: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert Date to  required format String, and send String to your UI layer

Comment: you can use unix time stamp instead

Comment: then you can easily convert it to any format in any language

Comment: Presumably by "JSON date" you mean an ISO 8601 date and time string with timezone, like "2016-03-11T21:28:41.579Z". Most browsers will successfully parse that with the Date constructor, however some won't so you should do it manually. A library can help, but a simple parser is 2 lines of code, 3 if you need to validate the values. Sending a time value might be better, since all browsers will successfully parse that. There are plenty of questions here about that.